# SQL server - extract and run queries on 20GB data

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I do have a BKS file which contains 15GB+ size. How do I extract the data and run queries on this? I was told that this is SQL Server data. Should I try to upload this to SQL Azure? Any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download sql server 2008 express edition from microsoft (free), and restore the backup on your dev machine..

Comment: Also how about extracting that BKS file?

Comment: #will that take 20gb data?

No - you'll need to download the free trial of the enterprise edition

Comment: @bob: SQL Server Express works only on 4GB (maximum) databases.

Comment: #"Also how about extracting that BKS file"... BKS is a windows backup file format.  Try using "restore" option in control panel.  There should be a BKF file in there (the sql  backup file) - use SQL Server management studio to restore this.

Comment: Thanks Bob, I use windows xp. Any ideas on how I can extract the BKS file? I cant find any option that takes this BKS file as input.

Comment: perhaps NTBackup? http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntbackup_command.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: still no luck, i cant figure out how to extract sql from the bks file

Comment: a bks file is a system restore backup file, from what I read, so I'd imagine you;d have to extract a BKF (sql backup) file from the BKS (nt backup) file.  -- Assuming the BKS file is a NTBackup file.  Maybe ask the person who provided the BKS file?

Comment: Thanks Bob.

I tried to open the BKS file in ntbackup and no idea how to get the BKF or SQl out of it. The person who provided the BKS cant not be reached unfortunately.

Comment: Still they don't have a way to take bks file as input on that. So still can't get anything out of the bks unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You must use any edition of SQL Server, restore database and run your queries. 
SQL Express not able to work with such amount data - there is limitation on 4GB (ver2010).

Comment: ok, will try and get an SQL server. But will that read the BKS file directly?

Comment: 2008 R2 has 10GB limit but probably still not enough storage for this situation

Answer (score 0):

It was actually a BAK file. Just run the standard restore database and point to the bks file.